# Generating QR codes for email-adresses and phone numbers

Tags: php, email, mobile, qr-code, phone-number

I have a website where people can contact each other, and quite often people also post emails or phone numbers in the ad or classifieds copy. I already replace the contact information with images so they cant be scraped by bot's or google, however i was thinking it would make sense to add a qr-code for each contact info found, so people can reply via their own phone without making typos.

I had a look at the google chart api for generating qr codes, but it seems like it just generates "plain text" qr codes. This means it will just show the submitted information as text on the screen, and the user has to copy/paste it into his email client or dialer to use it. BUT: If i use the tool at http://www.nzs.com/qr-code/ and scan the result with my smartphone, it will instantly open my browser and take me to this page, so there must be a way to specify a sort of mime-type for the information and the phone can choose the appropriate application to handle the information.

Can anyone tell me how to do this with the google chart api, or in PHP/GDI? I need to generate qr-codes for phone numbers and email adresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I use QuickMark for iOS.]

As far as I'm aware, this is a matter of detection on the scanning side, in combination with you providing proper source data.

What exactly did you encode for the URL? You need to include the protocol.

For example, [this query](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=www.example.com&choe=UTF-8) encodes "www.example.com" and is displayed as text. That's not a URL; it's just some text that happens to spell out a domain name.
But [this query](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.example.com&choe=UTF-8) encodes "http://www.example.com/" and is recognized as a URL.
[This](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=tel:18005555555&choe=UTF-8) is a hopefully useless phone number.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/qrcode/qrcode.html) on various QR code keywords.

Comment: Ah thanks, the tutorial is pretty usefull. QuickMark on Android needs "smsto:" to work, just "sms:" won't do it. emails work with or without "mailto:".

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). It's open source and there is a lot of sample code.